# DB Updater SQL Scripts sql file carry out failed

Tags: sql, .net, scripting, desktop-application

When i try carry out scripts from my local to db. It shows this error: Script BSoft Framework. DBUpdater.SQLScripts.00001071F.sql failed. No
Scripts were applied. Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in
abject ‘dboTranslation’ with unique index
UX_Translation_Key_Sprache’. The duplicate key value is (DE, Innert
weniger Tage nach Zahlungseingangsverbuchung stellen wir die neue
Lizenzdatei beret. Inr Server wird diese AUTOMATISCH herunterladen.

In MSSQl its inserted and no problem shows up. But when i try to update from my DBUpdater project then it shows above error.

I tried a bunch of times yesterday and still trying. I was expecting it should be carry out from local to db after DBupdater project runs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.